# What is a good plan for checking credit score/report monthly?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, fraud

I would like to monitor my credit score/report on a monthly basis (to make sure nobody is opening credit cards in my name or other fraudulent activities).  I remember hearing that too many requests for a credit score in a short amount of time can hurt your credit score.  I don't know if there's a similar thing for credit *score* requests.  I don't remember exactly, but I think each of the three credit reporting agencies will only allow me to generate a credit report for free once a year.

I want to generate a system where I can monitor my credit monthly to check for fraud.  I would prefer to view my full credit report monthly without having to pay for them but I don't think this is an option.  So my question is, what would be a good system to allow me to at least monitor my credit score monthly and monitor my full credit report as often as possible without having to pay anything?

Comment: credit karma.   .

Comment: What country, please edit the country tag

Comment: You never hurt your credit score by looking at your own report.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options out there that provide you with your score and report for free. I personally use Credit Karma (creditkarma.com). They offer weekly credit scores and report from TransUnion and Equifax (2 of the three major bureous) for free. These are soft inquiries, so checking it once a week won't affect your score.

Comment: Credit Karma is good for monitoring what's on your credit report--I use it--but keep in mind that the scores they provide are your Vantage, not your FICO, score.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of websites that provide free credit reports, and some of them also provide credit scores, I am not sure if all of the scores are free though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_credit_report_websites

There are two major credit score models: FICO and VantageScore. All of the websites from the above Wikipedia link use Vantage.

Answer (score -1):

For what you want to do free try Credit Karma, Quizzle, CreditSesame or WisePiggy. These are all completely fre.

You can also check out my full comparison of free credit scoring websites:

https://cafecredit.com/pdf/credit-score-websites-comparison.pdf

It's the biggest and up to date comparison on the internet.